# Tipfy & Jinja: Creating a logout URL for every page

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tipfy, jinja2

I have a jinja template with the usual boilerplate links, one of them being the "sign out" link.  The URL of this link has to be generated using Users.create_logout_url() before rendering a page.

I would like to avoid having to generate this URL and add it to my render_response for every single get/post handler.  I've looked into alternatives but have not found a functional way to go about this.

**BaseRequestHandler**

This seems like the cleanest approach, but I'm unsure how to go about it.  Would it be a case of

```
self.vars['logout_link'] = users.create_logout_url(self.request.path))
```

..and then, in all standard response handlers:

```
return render_response('template.html', **vars)
```

?

**Decorators**

This seems like another option, although seems slightly messy.  I suppose it would work in the same way (assigning the logout link to a local variable in a wrapper function).

**Context Processing?**

I'm using tipfy/jinja, which doesn't seem to support this as far as I can tell.

Any advice which path I should investigate further?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do something similar with Jinja / GAE and I use a BaseHandler + a template that I include. BaseHandler:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    ...
    def render_jinja(self, name, **data):
        data['logout_url']=users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/'+name+'.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(data))
```

Then I can inherit the basehandler for eg form handlers:

```
class FileUploadFormHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        ...
        self.render_jinja('contact_jinja', form=form, ...
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to add 'globals' to render_response - thanks!

Comment: As a bonus, this is an excellent way to keep template rendering DRY. I knew I was doing something wrong when I was copypasting several lines of code to lay out a basic site structure :)

Answer (score 4):

Having not used either framework, im not sure if there is a nice way to add it to the template. There may be some form of middleware you can implement, but as I say, I don't have experience with those frameworks.

However, have you consideded having a universal logout URL, with a handler which will give a 303 to the correct URL for the user?